# Inserting Disconnected Related Entities with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, insert, entity-framework-6, relationship

I have some data from an XML file that I have transposed and I can map to my Entities. So now I want to save them all to the database .

I was reading on SO [Can Entity Framework add many related entities with single SaveChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002845/can-entity-framework-add-many-related-entities-with-single-savechanges)

The accepted answer does not have too much info but this statement:

> 'You don`t need to save changes every time if you use objects
>   references to newly created objects not IDs:'

My entities are derived from a dataset tables which all have a related Id columns.

And I guessing the answer is more or less that the related entity was created with something like this : `item.SubItem = new SubItem();` 
rather than item.SubId = SubItem.Id;

So should I traverse my data tables and translate my dataset tables into Entities by creating the objects from the tables and adding them to the context.

So for each row in dt['Items'] if row has a subitem new SubItem {all values except the Id}..??

Any example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working to resolve the issue I discovered if I create a new object of my entity and map values to it excluding the ID column I can then assign this object back to the parent.

pseudo code is below:

```
myobject = new myobject(){ param1 = oldobject.param1}

myentityParent.ChildTableEntity.Add(myobject);
```